# Smarty templating inheritence - passing variables?

Tags: php, smarty, templating

Alright to start off I am using the latest Smarty version, and everything is setup.

My problem is that I have a main template for the whole site called layout.tpl, then sub-templates for each of the pages home.tpl, about.tpl ect...

index.php (for home)

```
require('Smarty.class.php');
// --
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->template_dir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/EMP3/view/templates';
$smarty->config_dir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/EMP3/view/config';
$smarty->cache_dir = 'C:/xampp/smarty/cache';
$smarty->compile_dir = 'C:/xampp/smarty/templates_c';
$smarty->display('home.tpl');
```

Home.tpl

```
{extends file="layout.tpl"}
{block name=title}Home{/block}
{block name=body}
<div>Sample</div>
{/block}
```

Layout.tpl

```
// Long html file which makes use of the blocks from home, about ect...
```

My problem is that the html content in layout.tpl is hidden or shown depending on whether the user is an admin or normal user. How do I pass in these PHP values to layout.tpl? Through home.tpl? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Smarty v3 and Inheritance and just going on your example code above, but how about `assign()`? I know when you have a template file that includes another file, all assigned variables are still valid, as well as being able to assign new ones in the `{include}` statement.

index.php (for home)

```
require('Smarty.class.php');
// --
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->template_dir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/EMP3/view/templates';
$smarty->config_dir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/EMP3/view/config';
$smarty->cache_dir = 'C:/xampp/smarty/cache';
$smarty->compile_dir = 'C:/xampp/smarty/templates_c';

$smarty->assign('some_header', 'hello!');

$smarty->display('home.tpl');
```

Home.tpl (unchanged)

Layout.tpl

```
<html>
    ...
    <h1>{$some_header}</h1>
    // Long html file which makes use of the blocks from home, about ect...
</html>
```